# Truncated SVD and PCA

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, pca, svd

Theoretically, the projection result of PCA and SVD is the same if the feature has mean 0. So I tried it on python.

```
from sklearn import datasets
cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# we can set our feature to have mean 0 by setting with_mean=False
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False,with_std=False)
scaler.fit(cancer.data)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(cancer.data)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca=PCA(n_components=3,svd_solver='randomized') 
pca.fit(X_scaled) 
X_pca=pca.transform(X_scaled) 

from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
svdm=TruncatedSVD(n_components=3,algorithm='randomized') 
svdm.fit(X_scaled) 
X_svdm=svdm.transform(X_scaled)
```

But when I print the result, it is different. Why is this happening?

```
print(X_pca)
print(X_svdm)
>>>[[1160.1425737  -293.91754364   48.57839763]
 [1269.12244319   15.63018184  -35.39453423]
 [ 995.79388896   39.15674324   -1.70975298]
 ...
 [ 314.50175618   47.55352518  -10.44240718]
 [1124.85811531   34.12922497  -19.74208742]
 [-771.52762188  -88.64310636   23.88903189]]
>>>[[2241.97427647  347.71556015  -27.53741942]
 [2372.40840267   56.90166991   23.86316187]
 [2101.8402797    11.94762737   30.41138602]
 ...
 [1424.53280954  -55.0217124    -3.5794351 ]
 [2231.65579282   19.99439854    3.31619182]
 [ 331.69302638   -5.29733966  -39.12136435]]
```

What should I fix so I can get the same result of both algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [help page for scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) :

> with_mean bool, default=True If True, center the data before scaling.
> This does not work (and will raise an exception) when attempted on
> sparse matrices, because centering them entails building a dense
> matrix which in common use cases is likely to be too large to fit in
> memory.

For PCA and SVD to give the same output, you need to center and scale the data, see also [this post for details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca), so if you do:

```
# which is also the default
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=True)
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(cancer.data)

pca=PCA(n_components=3,svd_solver='randomized')
pca.fit(X_scaled)
X_pca=pca.transform(X_scaled)

svdm=TruncatedSVD(n_components=3,algorithm='randomized')
svdm.fit(X_scaled)
X_svdm=svdm.transform(X_scaled)

X_pca
array([[ 9.19283683,  1.94858306, -1.12316567],
       [ 2.3878018 , -3.76817175, -0.52929196],
       [ 5.73389628, -1.0751738 , -0.55174751],
       ...,
       [ 1.25617928, -1.90229671,  0.56273027],
       [10.37479406,  1.67201011, -1.87702986],
       [-5.4752433 , -0.6706368 ,  1.49044385]])

X_svdm
array([[ 9.19283683,  1.94858307, -1.12316615],
       [ 2.3878018 , -3.76817174, -0.52929266],
       [ 5.73389628, -1.0751738 , -0.55174759],
       ...,
       [ 1.25617928, -1.90229671,  0.56273052],
       [10.37479406,  1.67201011, -1.87702935],
       [-5.4752433 , -0.67063679,  1.49044309]])
```

Comment: z = (x - u) / s
"where u is the mean of the training samples or zero if with_mean=False".
So if we set with_mean=True, the feature will also has mean 0?

Comment: yes if i understood your question correctly, yes this will center your feature, giving it a mean of zero, which is what you need for PCA